# Validate and submit form with no page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using jQuery validation and processing the form via ajax so I can avoid a page refresh. The problem I am running into is that I can't figure out where to place the ajax code in the validation function so that the form won't send data until it's been validated.

For example:

```
$('#ticket_purchasing').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            required: true
        },
        lastname: {
            required: true
        },
        phone: {
          required: true,
          digits: true,
        },
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
        address: {
          required: true
        },
        city: {
          required: true
        },
        state: {
          required: true
        }

    },
    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
      var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
      if (errors) {
        var message = "All fields in red must be filled*";
          $("div.error-message span").html(message);
          $("div.error-message").show();
        } else {
          $("div.error-message").hide();
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
      // Do stuff here
    }
});

$('form#ticket_purchasing').on('submit',function(e) {
      //Send the serialized data to mailer.php.
      $.ajax({
          url:'ticket-purchase.php',
          data:$(this).serialize(),
          type:'POST',
          success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            // $('#sponsorship_request').slideUp();
            // $('#ticket_purchasing').hide();
            // $('.seats-form').fadeIn(1000);
          },
          error:function(data){
            $("ticket_purchasing .error").show().fadeOut(5000); //===Show Error Message====
          }
      });
      e.preventDefault(); //=== To Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"===
      //$.post("mailer.php");
      //Take our response, and replace whatever is in the "form2"
      //div with it.
      // $('#form2').show();
  });
```

As you can see above I have both functions separated from each other, and because of this the form is submitting the data (which emails the information) even though it's not been validated yet. I tried using form.submit(); as show in the validator documentation, and putting the ajax code in there, but it was a no go with errors I couldn't solve.

Advice? I'm probably going at this all wrong haha.

Edit: Just added html for the form: https://gist.github.com/adrianrodriguez/26b6beee8bf5ba85a8ce

To be clear, the form works fine without the validation portion, meaning I can submit and collect the data without a page refresh without the use of the validation plugin.

Comment: At a minimum please also post your HTML. Preferably create a JS fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `$.ajax` call as the actual form submission should happen after validation in the `validate.submitHandler`.

```
$('form#ticket_purchasing').validate({

    //validation rules here

    //invalid handler goes here

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.post('ticket-purchase.php', $('#ticket_purchasing').serialize(), successCallback());
    }
});
```

BTW, changed your `$.ajax` to a `$.post`

Comment: Tried this here: https://gist.github.com/adrianrodriguez/82a61d52af253af76370 Not sure if I did this incorrectly or not, but when I tried it, the page just refreshed and no data was sent.

Comment: @adrianrodriguez, You should replace where I typed, `successCallback()` with your actual callback function.  Looking at your code, your success callback was, `function(data){ console.log(data) };

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone's help. I eventually realized that I was going at it all wrong and found this answer:

```
submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
      $.ajax({
        url: form.action,
        type: form.method,
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          // Do stuff here
          //$('#ticket_purchasing').hide();
          //$('.seats-form').fadeIn(1000);
        }
      });
      return false; // kill page refresh
    }
```

Instead of going the traditional way of the ajax submit I just had to use the "form" parameter already provided from jquery.validation.js and then grab data from its attributes.

Thanks for everyones help!

Comment: you asked where to put the ajax call, and my answer gave you the correct info.  The only diff between my answer and what you provided here is that you're using the lower level `$.ajax()` call instead of `$.post()`.  See [the jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post) for a description of `$.post()`.  Please consider accepting my answer as I did answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
});
```

between this.

Comment: Should all of the code above go in between the block you provided? How does it know to run the second function "after" the validation occurs?